# Find number counting days by condition from another column, R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, counting, days

My real data frame have more than 90000 rows and 30 `Ptt`

And then, I have one data frame like this:

```
Ptt      Date                      Area        
88734    2016-10-23 05:39:18       BA             
88734    2016-10-23 06:53:13       BA           
88734    2016-11-09 08:32:18       MI            
88734    2016-11-19 06:45:27       MI           
88734    2016-12-20 12:30:43       MI           
88734    2016-12-29 02:45:35       FA             
129041   2017-10-05 04:55:24       BA            
129041   2016-10-23 06:45:30       MI            
129041   2016-11-16 07:10:32       FA            
129041   2016-11-29 03:43:54       FA           
120941   2017-01-02 14:54:39       FA    



dt = data.table(Ptt= c("88734", "88734", "88734", "88734", "88734", "88734", "120941", "120941","120941","120941","120941"),
                date = c("2016-10-23 05:39:18",
                         "2016-10-23 06:53:13 ", 
                         "2016-11-09 08:32:18",
                         "2016-11-19 06:45:27",
                         "2016-12-20 12:30:43",
                         "2016-12-29 02:45:35",
                         "2017-10-05 04:55:24",
                         "2016-10-23 06:45:30",
                         "2016-11-16 07:10:32",
                         "2016-11-29 03:43:54",
                         "2017-01-02 14:54:39"),
                Area = c("BA", "BA", "MI", "MI", "MI", "FA", "BA", "MI", "FA", "FA", "FA"))
```

And I wanna two things. First, count how many days each `Ptt` have at each `area`. And second, how many days have at each `area`, but I don't have idea how to do this, someone know how?

About the first one, for example: `88734` have 1 day at `BA`, 3 days at `MI` and 1 day at `FA`, and so on.

Another example (not real): I have 2 repeated days for `88734`, `2016-10-23`, `2016-10-23`, and then `2016-11-09`, `2016-11-09`, `2016-11-09` (3 repeated days here), and then `2016-12-29` (1 day here). So, this `88734` have at total 3 days counting, not 6 days.

About the second, even have the same `date` for many `Ptt`, I need to sum all, I guess is like, sum all days for `88734` at `BA`, and then sum all days for `129031`, and then put all together. (I don't know if is the right reasoning)

For example (not real), `88734` have 10/08/2017, 10/08/2017 at `BA`, but `129041` have 10/08/2017, 10/08/2017, 10/08/2017 too at `BA`. So, have 2 days at `BA`, not 1.

I want this: (could be 2 news data frame)

```
#First one
Ptt      Area        Days
88734    BA           1
88734    MI           3 
88734    FA           1  
129041   BA           1 
129041   MI           1 
120941   FA           3

#Second one
Area     Days
BA        2
MI        4
FA        4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column that only has dates in it.

```
dt$date_col <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(dt$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %T"))
```

After that, you can count the number of unique dates for each `Ptt` & `Area` and only `Area`.

You can use `dplyr`, base R or `data.table` to do this.

**dplyr:**

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(Ptt, Area) %>% summarise(Days = n_distinct(date_col))

#  Ptt    Area   Days
#  <chr>  <chr> <int>
#1 120941 BA        1
#2 120941 FA        3
#3 120941 MI        1
#4 88734  BA        1
#5 88734  FA        1
#6 88734  MI        3
```

and

```
dt %>% group_by(Area) %>% summarise(Days = n_distinct(date_col))

# Area   Days
#  <chr> <int>
#1 BA        2
#2 FA        4
#3 MI        4
```

---

**Base R :**

```
aggregate(date_col~Ptt + Area, dt, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

and

```
aggregate(date_col~Area, dt, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

---

**data.table :**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .(days = uniqueN(date_col)), .(Ptt, Area)]
```

and

```
setDT(dt)[, .(days = uniqueN(date_col)), Area]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr` and `lubridate` to get your desired output:

```r
dt %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(date)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  count(Ptt, Area, name="Days")
```

returns

```r
      Ptt Area Days
1: 120941   BA 1
2: 120941   FA 3
3: 120941   MI 1
4:  88734   BA 1
5:  88734   FA 1
6:  88734   MI 3
```

and

```r
dt %>%
  mutate(date = as_date(date)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  count(Area, name="Days")
```

gives

```r
   Area Days
1:   BA 2
2:   FA 4
3:   MI 4
```